# proof for complex form of Lagrange's Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The proof for the following identity:

$$ | \sum_{i=1} ^n a_i b_i |^2 = \sum_{i=1} ^n |a_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|^2 - \sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n} |a_i \overline b_j -a_j \overline b_i|^2 $$

This specific version of the identity was found in Ahlfor's Complex Analysis as an exercise. Can the proof be done with the information given in the chapter before the exercise? That is,

$ a \overline a =|a|^2 $

$|\overline a|=|a|$

$|ab|^2 =a\overline a b\overline b=|a|^2|b|^2$

$|abc...|=|a|\bullet|b|\bullet|c|\bullet...$

$|a+b|^2=a \overline a + (a\overline b +b\overline a)+b\overline b =|a|^2+2Re(a\overline b)+|b|^2$

and basic complex number properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n$ complex numbers $z_1,\ldots,z_n$
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^nz_k\right|^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nz_k\right)\overline{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nz_k\right)}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nz_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\overline{z_k}\right)=\sum_{j,k=1}^nz_j\overline{z_k}.
$$

Comment: You only need to know that $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$ and then perform some algebraic manipulations to prove that identity.

Comment: how do we know that that LHS = middle term? is it trivially proved?

Comment: I just applied $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$ with $z=\sum_1^nz_k$.

Comment: i see. but surely the absolute value squared of a sum of something doesn't behave like an individual term does in that same situation? like the $|a+b|^2$ equation i gave in the question?

Comment: I don't understand you... If you're concerned because your expression for $|a+b|^2$ looks different than mine (when $n=2$ and $z_1=a,z_2=b$), you can check that they're actually the same...

Comment: what i meant was $|a|^2$ is different to $|a+b|^2$, as the first is $=a\overline a$ while the second is as shown in the question. so how come we can apply the first to a sum term, where the terms are more like $|a+b+c...|$ and not a single term like $|a|^2$?

Comment: also, how come in the outermost RHS of your equation you use different letters for the subscript? would it be wrong to use the same subscript $k$ for both $z$ and $\overline z$ instead of adding $j$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand where are you confused. The RHS is a double sum... (?)